# Display id, name, computer id and make of the computers allocated to employees provided model is either 'Precision' or 'Edge

Tags: inner-join

```sql
SELECT Id, EName, E.CompId AS CompId, Make FROM Employee E INNER JOIN Computer C ON E.CompId = C.CompId;
```

output should be

```
ID  ENAME           COMPID  MAKE
3   Emily Rayner    1002    Dell
5   Ayaz Mohammad   1003    Lenovo
```

Answer (score 0):

SELECT Id, Ename, E.Compid, Make
FROM Employee E INNER JOIN Computer C
ON E.Compid = C.Compid WHERE Model = 'Precision' OR Model = 'Edge';

Comment: Please provide some explanation and format the code. See [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)

Answer (score 0):

SELECT Id, Ename, E.Compid, Make FROM Employee E INNER JOIN Computer C ON E.Compid = C.Compid WHERE Model = 'Precision' OR Model = 'Edge'

Comment: Code only answers are not considered good practice. Please consider [Explaining how this answers the question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/300837/what-comment-should-i-add-to-code-only-answers)

Comment: This is exactly the same code as posted in [another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68379914/10871073).